# Performance hit when comments are included in a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I've noticed that complex SQL statements gradually attract comments just like development code.  For example -

```
select
    *
from
    table
where
    -- exclude 1 just because
    key <> 1
```

Or, a multi-line comment.

What is the performance hit when comments are included in a SQL query or is this just premature optimization?  I know this is dependent upon the size, etc. and I could test myself, but still wanted to ask the question, feel free to make assumptions. I'm mostly curious about MySQL.

Comment: The default is to not send the comments to the server: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_comments Unless that configuration option is changed, or you're using an older version of MySQL, this is a non-issue.

Comment: Is there any reason you haven't tested to see if there is a performance hit? If you can't generate a noticeable performance hit, there isn't one. For things like this, testing is the *only* way to know.

Comment: @bernie isn't that setting just for the mysql client tool?  Assume any connector.

Comment: @corsiKa did you read my entire question?  I knew someone was going to say this. :)  Didn't have time.

Comment: @Josh I did read the entire question - you said you could do it, but you didn't give any reason why. And as a general rule, if you knew someone would say it, it's probably because you knew you should have done it. It is hard for people to justify spending time on your problem if you aren't willing to spend time on your problem. Know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

There is a performance hit but it is negligible compared to actually running your query. I am having trouble finding hard data but comments are largely ignored (unless they are version specific functionality comments).

They can be extremely useful. For example, Facebook will add PHP call stacks as comments in their MySQL queries so they can easily tell where a query came from.